# Issue with React JS export

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

### Error

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of

### Switch.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { SwitchUnit } from './sitch_unit.jsx';

export default class MySwitch extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render(){
    return(<div>
        <SwitchUnit />
        <SwitchUnit />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### sitch_unit.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class SwitchUnit extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div className="xxx">xxx</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have exported `SwitchUnit` as `default`. Replace `import { SwitchUnit } from './sitch_unit.jsx'` to `import SwitchUnit from './sitch_unit.jsx'`

Answer (score 1):

You must import like this:

```
import SwitchUnit from './sitch_unit.jsx';
```

because SwitchUnit  is default method.